# Trouble in decoding the Path of the Blob file in Azure Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have set a Azure search for blob storage and since the path of the file is a key property it is encoded to Base 64 format.
While searching the Index, I need to decode the path and display it in the front end. But when I try to do that in few of the scenarios it throws error.

```
 int mod4 = base64EncodedData.Length % 4;
            if (mod4 > 0)
            {
                base64EncodedData += new string('=', 4 - mod4);
            }
            var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
            return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
```

Please let me know what is the correct way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try and use UTF8 encoding instead of ASCII?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [Base64Encode](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings#base64encode) and [Base64Decode](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings#base64decode) mapping functions - the encoding details are documented there.

In particular, if you're using .NET, you should use [HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokendecode(v=vs.110).aspx) with `UTF-8` encoding, not `ASCII`.